# Magento2 - Add custom attribute after SKU in e-mail

Tags: magento2, php, attributes, email

we are using magento 2.1.9ce

In the transactional sales e-mails is the sku shown.
I have found that the `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php` controls this sku.

Now I would like to add in the same line a custom attribute.
So we get: SKU: `defaultSKU` / `customSKU`

Now I have tried for testing to replace the default SKU with the custom attribute like this:

> return $item->getAttribute('artikelnummer');

But in my sales e-mail the SKU line stays empty.
The attribute name of the custom SKU is artikelnummer

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

> Vendor/Email/Block/Order/Email/Items/DefaultItems.php

```
$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('artikelnummer');
```

It will return your custom attribute value of a particular product.

Thanks

Comment: I tried this But the result in the email remains blank

Comment: try that code in here `<Vendor>/Email/Block/Order/Email/Items/DefaultItems.php`

Comment: also tried this without result. it remains empty. And the product does have a value in the attribute artikelnummer. so that cannot be the problem

Comment: can you please add your code.. how you are trying?

Comment: public function getSku($item)
    {
        if ($item->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku')) {
            /**return $item->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku');*/
            return $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('artikelnummer');
        } else {
            return $item->getSku();
        }
    }